# Are there 3-way dimmer switches that do not need travelers between them?

Tags: electrical, dimmer-switch

I put a few three-way switches in a house I did years ago that both dimmed but remember it requiring travelers.    Wondering if this has come along where we can retrofit existing 3-way switches (not dimmable)?

Comment: take look in to smart switches

Comment: Most in-wall smart switches I've seen that are designed as 2-way dimmers seem to require a traveller, though they may use it for signalling rather than as an alternate power path. The simpler but less responsive solution is to link the two switches/dimmers through software, with one actually being wired to the light and the other just a remote control sender

Comment: @keshlam - yea it seems the traveller is used to communicate the lighting level set on the other switch.     I set up a bunch of these like 10 years ago.   Figured with smart tech that they could "radio" this now without using some remote smart software.    I have a kitchen where I moved an island which had two lights with 2 2-way switches... both lights being moved and would really like them on dimmers.    I am going to be very surprised if no one figured out how to get two switches within range talking to each other in the past 10 years.

Comment: It can certainly be done. But companies don't seem interested in selling a hubless solution; they want you to buy into their ecosystem so you'll order the next device from them too

Comment: I don't think "2-way" is standard terminology for these multi-station switches.

Comment: @kreemoweet it is in Europe.  OP is referring to what Americans call "3-way".

Comment: @kreemoweet - sorry I am in europe half the time...   and I call it a culture-slip and I do it all the time... I know the term in the US, meant to use it but brain must have been thinking about something in europe at the time!

Answer (score 1):

I would look at something like Lutron Caseta that has wireless remote control switches. You can use it with a hub, but you can also pair remotes to switches directly, without a hub.

In this setup, you would install the "real" switch that's actually wired into the circuit at one of the locations. At the other location, install the remote control switch (which isn't hooked up to any wires) and just put a wirenut on the existing wiring to maintain continuity. I've done this several places throughout my house.

Comment: having remotes for light switches seem excessive but I will look into it.